# Reading different entities from same Spring JPA repository using Hibernate SINGLE_TABLE strategy

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I have base abstract class and 2 entities within same table, using descriminator-type inheritance in hibernate.

```
@MappedSuperclass()
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)
public abstract class Relation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(columnDefinition = "bigint unsigned", name = "id")
    public long id;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
    RelationType type;
}

@Table(name = "relation")
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorValue("0")
public class Ban extends Relation {
    // ...
    public RelationType type = RelationType.BAN;
}
```

Same for second entity but with @DiscriminatorValue("1").

The problem is: when reading these entities via single repository, SQL doesn't contain discriminator value in 'where' condition.

Separate repository for every entity is a must?

UPDATE:
it doesn't work even with separated repositories

```
@NoRepositoryBean
public interface BaseRelationRepository<T extends Relation> extends JpaRepository<T, Long> {
}


public interface BanRepository extends BaseRelationRepository<Ban> {
@Query("from Ban b where b.user = :user")
List<Ban> findAllByUser(@Param("user") User user);
```

this method/query reads all records without conditioning by @DiscriminatorValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not explained *why* you want to restrict by the discriminator column in cases where Hibernate judges it to be unnecessary, so it's pretty hard to answer your question definitively.

But there are a couple of things Hibernate provides:

- The annotation `@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)`, usually used in cases where the table contains extra data not mapped to an entity class.
- The HQL `type()` function for which you may find examples [here](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/6.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql-functions-typecasts) in the documentation.

**UPDATE**

I didn't notice immediately, but your error here was the use of `@MappedSuperclass` instead of `@Entity` for the superclass of the `SINGLE_TABLE` inheritance hierarchy.

If you look carefully in your log, you will find the following warning message logged by Hibernate:

> A class should not be annotated with both @Inheritance and @MappedSuperclass. @Inheritance will be ignored for: Relation.

So:

1. It does *not* make sense to write `@MappedSuperclass @Inheritance(SINGLE_TABLE)` in JPA because mapped superclasses are never a part of the entity hierarchy.
2. What you have done here is map three classes which as far as JPA/Hibernate is concerned are *unrelated entity classes* to the same table.

So the fix is to either:

- just replace `@MappedSuperclass` with `@Entity`, as shown in thousands of examples you can find online, or, alternatively,
- use `@DiscriminatorOptions(force=true)` on each of the subclasses (though they will each need to also explicitly declare the discriminator column), as I already mentioned above.

Comment: What do you mean 'unnecessary' ? When I read specific entity - I want exactly these records, not all, ignoring 'type'. It's just have no sense.

Comment: Because polymorphism is a thing in Java? But quite obviously you know better than the JPA spec and the most successful ORM solution ever. Sorry for bothering you, I thought you were asking a question.

Comment: Sorry, I just don't understand how it related with polymorphism. Every entity has DiscriminatorValue that must be used.

Comment: OK, so if I query `Relation`, then I expect *all* subtypes of `Relation` to be returned. (For example, `Ban` is a subtype of `Relation`, so it matches the query due to polymorphism.) So in that case Hibernate does not need to include a discriminator. OTOH if I explicitly query `Ban`, then it *does* need a discriminator because there are other types in that table which are not instances of `Ban`. And so it will always include a discriminator in that case.

Comment: I mean, just check out the difference between the generated SQL for `from Relation` (no discriminator) and `from Ban` (yes discriminator).

Comment: May be i wrote unclear... I never read 'Relation' it's just abstract base class. I always read it's inheritors - Ban or other, that must be read according to discriminator values that is NEVER used.

Comment: check plz post update, i separated repositories but still no effect

Comment: Oh wait, I just noticed the error in your annotations.

Comment: Yes, thanks! Base abstract class must be annotated: 
@Entity @DiscriminatorColumn(name="type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.INTEGER)